# Php phpchartdir530 dll not found

Tags: php, linux, dll, centos, cacti

I have a problem about php on centos. When I want to run php script I have problem like that below,

```
# php removespikes.php -R=/var/www/html/cacti-0.8.8a/rra/gyt_traffic_in.rrd
```

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/phpchartdir530.dll' -
>   /usr/lib64/php/modules/phpchartdir530.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please check this and install  on your centos :- http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdphpdoc/phpinstall.htm

Comment: thanks for replyi i fix this problem. ı uncomment line 0 chartdirector.ini.

Comment: Good to here that your problem is resolved.